# summing two numbers represented as arrays, a test case is missed

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the problem of summing two numbers represented as arrays containing digits, the outcome should be the an array representing digits making the result of the sum, but can't seem to cover every possible case, how can I handle such case a = [9, 9], b = [1] in the shortest way in the following code:

Code:

```
//#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int Sum(int a[], int b[], int n, int m) {
    int *sum = new int[n];
    int i = n - 1, j = m - 1, k = n - 1;
    int c = 0, s = 0;
    while (j >= 0) {
        s = a[i] + b[j] + c;
        sum[k] = (s % 10);
        c = s / 10;
        k--;
        i--;
        j--;
    }
    while (i >= 0) {
        s = a[i] + c;
        sum[k] = (s % 10);
        c = s / 10;
        i--;
        k--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        cout << sum[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int *a = new int[n];
    int *b = new int[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        cin >> b[i];

    if (n >= m)
        Sum(a, b, n, m);
    else
        Sum(b, a, m, n);

    delete[] a, b;
    return 0;

}
```

In the code above, for a = [9, 9], b = [1], the output is 00, when it should be 100.

Comment: please explain what the code is supposed to do. Eg `sum[k] = (s % 10); c = s / 10;` isnt something I would expect in code that sums two arrays. Are you calculating the sum of all digits?

Comment: or are the arrays containing the digits of integers and you want to sum those integers and get the result again as an array of digits?

Comment: Off topic: you seem to be allocating memory with `new`, but you are forgetting to `delete` it, effectively leaking it. If you used `std::vector`: memory management would be done for you.

Comment: Please learn how to create a simpler [mcve]. For example, if you know there's a problem with some specific input, then you could hard-code those values. for example your `main` function could be as simple as `int main() { const int n = 2; const int m = 1; int a[n] = { 9, 9 }; int b[m] = { 1 }; Sum(a, b, n, m); }`

Comment: I also recommend that you learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through your code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. Doing that usually helps with problems like this, as it makes it easy to see when and where something happens which isn't supposed to happen. Also try to program more incrementally, where you write just small pieces of code that you test before writing more. The `Sum` function could be written in small incremental pieces to better help you find errors and problems.

Comment: Lastly, the `Sum` function have a memory leak. Please learn how to use [standard C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) like e.g. [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Also please learn how to use longer more descriptive names for your variables, as well as how to write comments describing your code and what it does and *why* it does that. That will make your code much easier to read and understand. And if a function shouldn't really return a value, then declare it as returning `void` and don't return anything.

Comment: You should take the above comments to heart. Please update the question.

Comment: @trincot I did edit it. Is that enough?

Comment: Things to clarify: "are the arrays containing the digits" (I quote from above comment). Should the output really be one number, or consist of several output *digits*, or be an array? How come that the example should output a double 0? Why not 100? Why not 0? Why not [1,0,0]? The question should be phrased as such, that no-one is left with these questions. Imagine that the reader knows literally nothing about what you are doing. One keyword that is missing is *digit*. It is a very precise word (different in meaning from *number*), and I have the impression you want decimal digits.

Comment: @trincot I see, I rephrased it.

Comment: @trincot I have accepted, and I solved the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoiler alert: I will not write code for you, since this seems to be homework.

Since your arrays are representing numbers, basically when you sum [9,9] with [1], you have the following operation:

```
 99+
  1
---
100
```

Which is equivalent with

```
099+
001
---
100
```

So, when you run out of digits, you will just need to use 0 as an operator. However, you will need to take into account the following:

## Difference in digit number results in difference of indexes

If a number is longer than another, then, in their sum you will need to compute the difference in length between the two and take that into account whenever you are summing digits.

## The number of operations

You will need at least as many operations as the number of digits of the longest number in the operation, even if most of the operations are just storing a digit in the sum. I say *at least* because there might be one additional operation, see the next section

## The number of digits in the result

It makes sense to loop through your digits from right to left first to check whether the number of digits of the longest number will be enough or not, so you will be able to do the expensive operation of allocating an array for the sum once. After the allocation, just compute the sum as explained earlier.

Comment: @Nap okay, however, my answer should still guide you towards the solution.

Comment: @Nap have you been successful in solving the issue?